# Multiple database providers in Silex

Tags: doctrine, silex

I'm new to this framework. By default applications uses  `CouchBaseServiceProvider`

```
   $app->register(
        new CouchBaseServiceProvider(),
        array(
            'dbs.options' => $app['dbLogins']
        )
    );
```

But now, there is a need to connect `postgreSQL` database and update some records in it, but I don't know how to use second database provider. So I've registered second provider:

```
$app->register(
    new DoctrineServiceProvider(),
    array(
        'dbs.options' => $app['pgSQL']
    )
);
```

Can anyone explain how to use `postgreSQL` database in controller or model, while by default is used `CouchBaseServiceProvider`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the problem for you is that both providers use the same `db` service name?

By checking the source code I see that the [default `db` service](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/DoctrineServiceProvider.php#L111) is just an alias to `dbs.default`. So I think you can access the connection you desire directly by its name [see line 76](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/DoctrineServiceProvider.php#L76) like:

```
$app['dbs']['my_other_connection']
```

This is basically the same as shown in the documentation under [Using multiple databases](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.3/providers/doctrine.html#using-multiple-databases).